# NullReferenceException when raycasting in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am trying to use a raycast that writes the name of the object that hits and the position and when shooting the ray it gives a null reference exception.
It happens at this line Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
Here is the code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

Camera cam;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    cam = Camera.current;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //a ray is created
        Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        //it is then casted
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            Debug.Log("We have hit " + hit.collider.name + " " + hit.point);
            
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So probably something is null. Did you debug to figure it out? Also, rather than give us a line number expecting us to count the lines (hoping you pasted in the right code), you could make it a little easier and actually mark which line.

Comment: Did you place a camera? `Camera.current;` may be null?

Answer (score 1):

The property [`Camera.current`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-current.html)

> The camera we are **currently rendering** with, for low-level render control only (Read Only).

is only set/valid within the event messages [`OnRenderImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnRenderImage.html), [`OnPreRender`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnPreRender.html) and [`OnPostRender`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnPostRender.html)

the rest of the time it is `null`.

---

You want to rather use [`Camera.main`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html)!

> The first enabled Camera component that is tagged "MainCamera" (Read Only).